# PrinterWriter giving FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, file

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("testfile.txt", "UTF-8");
```

Following this link:

[How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file)

it does not specify a path link in the first argument of PrinterWriter(), but only a file name. I followed it exactly, but it then shows a FileNotFoundException. I ran the app once, but the exception still shows up. I assumed after running the app, a file would be automatically created, but it doesn't seem to do that. I am using eclipse for android, so I'm not sure where the file should have been created. If there is any confusion don't hesitate to ask questions, thanks.

Comment: Well presumably the `testfile` argument is specifying a file in a directory that doesn't exist...

Comment: Well it sounds like you need to look for an Android-specific tutorial, that explains what the current directory is going to be, where you can write files etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried, but either my googling skills are horrible, or there doesn't seem to be any good, informational website on android files. Is it possible that you can point me to one?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you just have no permission to create files in the root directory. Try this:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(context.getFilesDir(), "testfile.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

or if you want to save file on sdcard

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "testfile.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

Don't forget to add permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in this case

Answer (score -2):

I don't develop on android but according to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and this [code](http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52c5d38bda0adc19d8191b1b/java.io.PrintWriter?tag=coyote) here, I think you might have to wrap an `OutputStream` with a PrintWriter for it to work.

Comment: Nonsense. See the last constructor listed in your first citation.

Comment: @EJP I was going by the "Class Overview" of the first link. Looking again, I see there is a constructor for how the OP used it but the class overview did specify its use as a wrapper. It also says it does not throw an IOException when it clearly did for OP so I'm not sure if any of that is correct.

Comment: PrintWriter(String, String) throws FileNotFoundException. Have another look. This answer should be deleted.